# Load different XML value sets in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, header, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

I am loading PreferenceActivity (Preferences.java) from preferences.xml. All values changed in this PreferenceActivity is getting saved in the XML file packagename_preferences.xml

packagename_preferences.xml is the default shared preference file.

Now, I want to load values from a different XML files, lets say mode1_preferences.xml or mode2_preferences.xml or mode3_preferences.xml in the same PreferenceActivity (Preferences.java). This mode will be depending on the user.
So, the layout remains same but value sets are different.

I have used this below code in onCreate of PreferenceActivity

```
PreferenceManager prefMgr = getPreferenceManager();
prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesName("myPref1");
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

However, getPreferenceManager() returns NULL

How can I load a different XML value file in my PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method. If you put `null` or `""` (empty string) for type, you'le get default shared preferences xml.

```
public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context context, String type) {
    String sharedPreferenceName = type == null  ||  type.isEmpty()
                    ? context.getPackageName() + "_preferences" 
                    : type;

    return SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(sharedPreferenceName,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```